# ssh-add: could not add identity xxx agent refused operation

Tags: ssh, debian, ssh-keys, openssh

I copied identities `id_rsa` from an old computer to a new one, both running the same version of Debian. When I do `ssh-add` I get:

```
Could not add identity xxx: agent refused operation
```

Why?

Comment: do you have an ssh-agent running? what does SSH_AUTH_SOCK point to?

Comment: @Ente what do i say, stupid me, it was not running. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `ssh-agent` is not running or `ssh-add` can not connect to it via `SSH_AUTH_SOCK`.

Answer (score 19):

To get ssh-agent running:

```
eval `ssh-agent`
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case the `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` socket was not pointing to the correct ssh-agent instance. So what I did was to

1. kill all ssh-agents (I had 2, for some reason),
2. run the agent in debug mode with `ssh-agent -d` so that it printed its socket,
3. set `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` to that value and run `ssh-add <key file>`, which worked

Originally`SSH_AUTH_SOCK` was `/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.3sfgCOEaij/Listeners` (I am on Mac) while when I start ssh-agent, it creates `/var/folders/07/46ycckp94db7k29k012nxjp00000gn/T//ssh-bWhNQhrLKeVJ/agent.35804`, i.e. a completely different path. I have no idea where the original one came from. (It is also possible that the GPG Suite and its `gpg-agent` are somehow messing things up.)

#### Update

I think I know what the problem was. The original SSH_AUTH_SOCK (...apple.../Listeners) is likely set by Apple's ssh-agent, while I have been starting an openssh agent installed via brew (`where ssh-agent` -> `/usr/local/bin/ssh-agent` which is symlink to `/usr/local/Cellar/openssh/9.1p1/bin/ssh-agent`). That is also why I had to ssh-agent instances - the first was the OS-started apple one, the second was the openssh one I started in the terminal.

And my `ssh-add` was failing b/c apple ssh-agent is old and does not support *-sk keys (sk = security key, with support for FIDO/U2F Support, see https://www.openssh.com/txt/release-8.2).

##### Attempted permanent fix

I have changed the ssh-agent started by OSX to be the brew-installed one - in `/System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.openssh.ssh-agent.plist` I changed the path (the first of ProgramArguments) from ~/usr/bin/ssh-agent~ to